# How to find the IP Address of incoming requests in couchbase logs? (Non REST API-Non Web Console requests)

Tags: node.js, couchbase

I have gone through all the logs given in the below link but have not been able to find the IP Address:

https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/3.x/admin/Misc/Trbl-logs.html

I am hitting the Couchbase bucket via code and not via REST APIs or the Web Console. Here is a piece of my code:

```js
var couchbase = require("couchbase");

var userCouchbaseIp = subscriptionConf.CouchbaseIp;

var couchbaseBucketName = subscriptionConf.couchbaseBucketName;

var cluster = new couchbase.Cluster(userCouchbaseIp);

var Bucket = cluster.openBucket(couchbaseBucketName);

var Key = "abcd";

Bucket.get(Key, function(errGetKey, resGetKey) {

    console.log("trial console");
    if (errGetKey) {
        console.log("errGetKey: ", errGetKey);
    } else {
        console.log("resGetKey: ", resGetKey);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The official SDK identify themselves using the `HELO` command when communicating with the Data Service. This is logged in the Data Services logs `/opt/couchbase/var/log/memcached.log*`.

This is what a log entry on 5.5-beta look like.

```
2018-04-27T10:14:32.031425Z INFO 47: HELO [{"a":"libcouchbase/2.8.6 (Darwin-17.3.0; x86_64; Clang 9.0.0.9000039)","i":"00000000ae092f72/26a9bd662aca89f5"}] TCP nodelay, XATTR, XERROR, Select bucket, Snappy, JSON [ 10.111.180.1:50149 - 10.111.180.101:11210 (not authenticated) ]
```

It will say the version of the SDK being used(`libcouchbase/2.8.6`), the connection (`10.111.180.1:50149 - 10.111.180.101:11210`) and the capabilities the SDK has(`TCP nodelay, XATTR, XERROR, Select bucket, Snappy, JSON`).